# What is the difference between atomic broadcast and atomic multicast?

Tags: distributed-computing, terminology, broadcast, multicast

It is not clear to me why some papers use one or another term. I think they are the same thing: maybe atomic multicast is actually atomic broadcast that is implemented using IP multicast (like ring Paxos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In distributed systems theory, it is not related to using IP multicast or any other implementation detail. Actually, most of the time it is a matter of personal preference of the author and you can safely assume that they mean the same.

In detail, to be strict, when you say multicast you are assuming that not all processes are necessarily intended to receive all messages. When you say broadcast, you are assuming that all processes are targeted by all messages. The ambiguity arises as follows: As often multicast algorithms are layered on top of membership management, an abstract protocol that multicasts to all members in the context of a view is pretty much indistinguishable from one that broadcasts to all processes in the system model. Hence, you can describe it as either multicast or broadcast. It really depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

The term [Atomic Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_broadcast) is more related to a **single central entity**, usually called a ***sequencer***, which is enforcing and sending a total ordered set of messages, usually called the ***event-stream***. How it sends the messages (broadcast, multicast, unicast, tcp, etc.) is not its main characteristic, or at least it shouldn't be. Adding to what @jop has said, there are big technical differences between UDP broadcast and UDP multicast when it comes to the TCP/IP protocol. For example:

- Multicast can travel across subnets, broadcast cannot
- Multicast usually requires [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol), broadcast does not
- Most kernel-bypass network cards will accelerate multicast, but not broadcast

That does not mean that UDP broadcast should never be used. Some networks might not support multicast but will support broadcast. Ideally a messaging system will support several transport mechanisms:

- UDP Multicast
- UDP Unicast
- UDP Broadcast
- TCP
- Memory
- Shared Memory
- DUAL (TCP + UDP)

For an example of an atomic broadcast messaging system which is not tied to any specific transport mechanism, you can check [CoralSequencer](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/state-of-the-art-distributed-systems-with-coralmq/).

**Disclaimer:** I'm one of the developer of CoralSequencer.